# Saving R Dataframe as filename based on objects

Tags: r

I have some objects in R that can change from time to time:

```
    beginning <- "Our_Office_Preface"
    query_type <- "PA_"
    date <- "2018_06_08_"
    office_query_type <- "dis_"
    input_FY <- 2015
    filename <- paste(beginning,"",query_type,"",date,"",office_query_type,"",input_FY,sep="")
```

and I'm trying to write a dataframe as a tab delimited txt file. I'm trying to save it as `filename` and having a hard time making it tab delimited.

```
df <- data.frame(name=c('Inst1','Inst2','Inst3','Inst4','Inst5','Inst6','Inst7','Inst8','Inst9','Inst10'), num=c(1,5,6,7,4,6,5,7,8,4))
```

these two lines

```
write.table(df , file=paste(filename, ".txt", sep="\t", quote = FALSE))
write.table(df , file=paste(filename, ".txt", sep="\t"), append = FALSE, quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
```

both produced this error

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open the connection
```

Could I get some assistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just misplaced your closing parenthesis on the `paste` function.
`sep = "\t"` is a `write.table` argument and it's being passed to `paste` instead.

Close the `paste` function after `".txt"` and it should work.

```
write.table(df , file=paste(filename, ".txt"), sep="\t", quote = FALSE)
```

Comment: Derp! I knew it would be something like that. Thank you!